# display checkbox results on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I am working on a webpage that shows the information about cars using GET variable from URL. Example url:

```
http://www.example.com/list.php?cat=cars.
```

Sample output:

```
Company       Car          Price

Maruti        Alto         200000
Hyundai       i10          400000
Hyundai       i20          600000
Honda         Civic        600000
Maruti        Zen          150000
Tata          Safari      1000000
```

My page has some form checkbox to filter company, car etc.

form:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="list.php?cat=cars">
<input type="checkbox" value="m" name="car"/>Maruti
<input type="checkbox" value="Hy" name="car"/>Hyundai           
<input type="checkbox" value="H" name="car"/>Honda               
<input type="checkbox" value="T" name="car"/>Tata
</form>
```

All i could find till now is a script that displays the output as "car=m" if i just check Maruti checkbox & m,H,T if i check Maruti, Honda and Tata checkboxes and so on as an alert box.

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e) {
    var data = {};
    var dataStrings = [];

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            if (data[this.name] === undefined) data[this.name] = [];
            data[this.name].push(this.value);
        }
    });

    $.each(data, function(key, value)
    {
        dataStrings.push(key + "=" + value.join(','));
    });

    var result = dataStrings.join('&');

    alert(result);

    <!-- $.post('/ajax-post-url/', data); -->
    if (history.pushState) {
        history.pushState(null, null, loc.pathname + '?' + data);
    }
});
              });
```

Now i want to change the output on the same page when one or more checkbox clicked. Fresher to jquery and AJAX. Thanks...

Comment: I can't understand your purpose? What do you want?

Comment: i want user to check one or multi checkbox and change output according to that checkbox or checkboxes.